# VSCode Default Settings Tab Is Gone

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever you open settings.json usually two windows open up, which are default settings and user settings.

However, whenever I open up settings it only shows the settings.json file in the editor tab. It would be nice to be able to see the default settings of extensions and other things. Below is an image of what I'm talking about.

My settings file:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Comment: Don't post code (config) as image - post it as text

Comment: There's no way for the OP to post his problem as text.

Answer (score 1):

The split json settings view was removed as the default in VS Code 1.31: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_use-simple-text-editor-for-editing-settings-as-json

For now, you can still set `workbench.settings.useSplitJSON` to restore it. However this option may be removed in the future

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want these two settings:

> // Determines which settings editor to use by default.
>
> //  - ui: Use the settings UI editor.
>   //  - json: Use the JSON file editor.

```
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
```

and

> // Controls whether opening settings also opens an editor showing all
>   default settings.

```
"workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
```